# Calculate how many month 'January' have occurred between two dates in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to get how many January's have occurred between two dates in TSQL.

I.e. If any day in January in a particular year has been included then this counts as 1 per year rather than multiple times per month.

As an example, the following would give the result = 1

```
declare @date1 datetime = '2018-09-01 00:00:00.000';
declare @date2 datetime = '2019-02-01 00:00:00.000';
```

As an example, the following would give the result = 1, as there has been 1 day into January

```
declare @date1 datetime = '2018-09-01 00:00:00.000';
declare @date2 datetime = '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000';
```

As an example, the following would give the result = 0 as there has been no days in January

```
declare @date1 datetime = '2018-09-01 00:00:00.000';
declare @date2 datetime = '2018-11-01 00:00:00.000';
```

As an example, the following would give the result = 2 as there has been two occurrences of January

```
declare @date1 datetime = '2017-09-01 00:00:00.000';
declare @date2 datetime = '2019-11-01 00:00:00.000';
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, define what *you* mean by "January".  Do you mean any date in January, the full month, a particular day?

Comment: Thanks, i've added a bit more description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`DATEDIFF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`DATEPART()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

You can test to see if your start and end dates are outside a January date and then add -1...

```
DECLARE @startdate AS DATETIME = '2015-02-01'
DECLARE @enddate   AS DATETIME = '2019-06-01'

SELECT
    DATEDIFF(yy, @startdate, @enddate) 
    + 1 
    + CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(m, @startdate) > 1 AND 
           DATEPART(m, @enddate) > 1 
        THEN -1
        ELSE  0
    END
```

I'm not sure how quick this would be over large datasets, however.  If you are going to compare lots of data with a particular date/time set, then I would recommend testing [Squirrel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58377116/1945782).

To modify this for a different month, simply change the `CASE` clause like so...

```
+ CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(m, @startdate) < 2 AND DATEPART(m, @startdate) > 2 AND 
         DATEPART(m, @enddate)   < 2 AND DATEPART(m, @enddate)   > 2
```

The `2` in the `CASE` statement is the month, so just change this to the appropriate month number.

If you'd like to alter this for *any* month, then include a parameter for the month number you're looking for...

```
+ CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(m, @startdate) < @month_number AND 
         DATEPART(m, @startdate) > @month_number AND 
         DATEPART(m, @enddate)   < @month_number AND 
         DATEPART(m, @enddate)   > @month_number
```

This could also be turned into a [function (UDF)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: based on your sample data `2015-02-01` to `2019-06-01` it gives result of `3`. But it should be `4` `Jan` months :- `2016 Jan, 2017 Jan, 2018 Jan, 2019 Jan`

Comment: @Squirrel: You're right - missed the `+1` out of my edit!

Comment: I like both the answers, but I think this one give me the solution I want without having a CTE, which could get quite large if I do over many years.  Thanks so much for your answer

Comment: @Paul Out of interest, how can I change the month from January to a different month?

Comment: @user3284707: I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

one way is to you recursive CTE to generate the various month and count for `Jan`

```
declare @date1 datetime = '2018-09-01 00:00:00.000';
declare @date2 datetime = '2019-02-01 00:00:00.000';

; with rcte as
(
    select  [date] = @date1
    union all
    select  [date] = dateadd(month, 1, [date])
    from    rcte
    where   eomonth([date]) < @date2
)
select  count(*)
from    rcte
where   datepart(month, [date]) = 1
```

or you may use a tally table if you have one

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had used these before but I wasn't sure how efficient they would be over a large datasets?

Comment: use a `tally table` if you are not satisfy with the performance of `rcte`